# What is the relationship between these two characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, npc, tomb-of-annihilation

In the [Baldur's Gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#BaldursGate) section of the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, it is mentioned that the former Grand Duke was Dillard Portyr (emphasis mine):

> The current Grand Duke is Ulder Ravengard, who is joined by Dukes Thalamra Vanthampur, Belynne Stelmane, and **Dillard Portyr, the former grand duke**, who ceded the post to Ravengard after the city’s recent troubles.

In the published adventure Tomb of Annihilation there is a character with the same last name, [Liara Portyr](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/monsters-and-npcs#LiaraPortyr), but as far as I could find the only mention of the character's family ties is:

> Liara comes from an influential family in Baldur’s Gate and has held her post for the past three years.

It seems likely that these two characters are from the same family but is there any information on how they are related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Liara is *likely* a granddaughter (or similar) of Dillard's.

In the campaign book *Murder in Baldur's Gate* there is a listing for Dillard Portyr on page 36 which reads:

> **The Grand Duke Dillard Portyr**
>
> Dillard Portyr is a short, portly man in his sixties. His once black hair is now gray and sparse, and he wears a shabby wig out of habit rather than vanity. A veteran investor, shipping-fleet owner, and trader, Portyr recently pulled back from the business world following a string of sour deals. Now he is using his time to enjoy the comforts that his wealth and title have provided him. **Having outlived two wives and three sons**, Duke Portyr now lives quietly in a relatively unassuming manor in the Temples district that a handful of devoted servants maintain.

The lore only talks about those relatives which Dillard has outlived. This list is probably not exhaustive (meaning it doesn't mention those relatives who are still living) so it's possible the Liara is a daughter who is still living and simply not mentioned. Liara is described as:

> Commanding Fort Beluarian is a lawful evil Flaming Fist blaze (major) named Liara Portyr (see appendix D), who answers directly to **Grand Duke Ulder Ravengard** of Baldur’s Gate. **Liara is 47 years old** and has held her post for the past three years.

In the Murder in Baldur's Gate, *Ulder Ravengard* is a blaze of the Flaming Fist (per the info on page 43). Since he's now a Grand Duke, this means that Tomb's events, canonically, take place after those of Murder at Baldur's Gate.

[This Wiki article about Dillard](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dillard_Portyr) mentions him surviving a coup in 1386. The only source cited on that Wiki page lists the *Murder in Baldur's Gate* book (pages 4 & 5) but no years are mentioned on those pages (or really anywhere, from what I can see). Yay for bad citations! The information on when this event happened might actually come from [one of the novels](https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00CJDFM9A/ref=dp_st_078691985X) but I don't have access to these so this is just a guess.

[This article about Liara from the same Wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Liara_Portyr) lists her as being active during the 1480s/1490s. If you peg the year at 1490 (to keep things simple) and do the math, 57 years passed between the coup and Liara's birth. Thus, we know that Dillard was probably in his 70s when she was born.

Given this timeline, Liara likely a granddaughter (or grandniece, etc, if the name is consistent between branches of the family) of Dillard's. Either that, or she's Dillard's daughter and we discover that he was (ahem) *performing admirably* well past his prime.

If we ignore the poorly cited Wiki articles, we at least know from the sourcebooks cited above that both their lives overlapped that Ulder Ravengard and his transition from blaze to Grand Duke. This confirms that Liara is younger than Dillard and within one or two generations.

---

Also Lead designer Chris Perkins has confirmed that they are related [in a tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/25/is-liara-portyr-related-to-dillard-portyr-member-of-baldurs-gate-council-of-four/) but not indicated the exact nature of their relationship.

Comment: I would only question the "must". If he is in his sixties, at most there is a 22 year age gap, at minimum 13. Probably rules out granddaughter, but could also be sister/cousin/niece (Or even in weird circumstances an aunt).

Comment: @john I don't know that the two ages are being tallied concurrently. Meaning: It could be that Dillard's is recorded as being 60 (some years pass) and then Liara's is recorded as being 47. But the fact that Ravengard is present in both sources suggests that no great amount of time has passed between the recording of ages, so your math is probably accurate. I've tweaked the wording of the answer to reflect this, thanks :)

Comment: I would have to look again, but there was something in one of the wikis where the dates indicated unlikely to be daughter, but on mobile atm. I'll look again later.

Comment: That might be it, I missed the heckuva lifespan and interpreted it wrong. I've got a tweet out to Chris Perkins to clarify, we'll see if he responds.

Comment: @johnP lol wow. I went ahead and tweaked the answer again to reflect the info from the Wiki articles. In the event that Mr. Perkins doesn't respond, do you think the updated answer is acceptable?

Comment: Eminently so. It's basically what I would have posted, I was going to look through a couple of the books I have at home to see what there was, but this was all that I found too.

Answer (score 6):

### Dillard Portyr is Liara Portyr's uncle

The release of the adventure Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus has clarified this issue. For example, in chapter 1, the [Basilisk Gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/a-tale-of-two-cities#TheBasiliskGate) section (emphasis mine):

> Zodge also knows that Liara Portyr, who commands the Flaming Fist stronghold of Fort Beluarian in Chult, has been recalled to Baldur’s Gate by **her uncle**, Duke Dillard Portyr.

This is also mentioned in other passages of the book, leaving their relationship now clarified.